# Conditional statement for a addition or substraction assignment operator

Tags: c#, .net, assignment-operator

If there a short hand way to do a conditional statement for the following line below?  I would like to do a conditional statement to determine a `+=` or `-=` in .NET C#.

```
  var team1 = 1700;
  team1 += delta
```

Example: team1 (true ? += : -=) delta

Comment: eh, what are you asking? `team1 += (true ? delta : 0)`?

Comment: Or are you trying to say, `team1 += (true ? delta : -delta)`?

Comment: @BurnsBA I'm interpreting this request as the latter.

Comment: Yes the latter is the correct way

Comment: Using .net 6 preview features, you can define `INumber` class comparable to int, but define `operator +`(bool) overload to return deferred execution container for addition/subtraction, then overload *that* class `operator +` (int) and finally arrive at `team1 = team1 + true + delta`.  (obscuring sometimes that will subtract). So technically, short(er) hand conditional add/subtract. But would not recommend, for multiple reasons. Otherwise no, operator language spec is more restricted than, say, c++.